# Convert wireshark filter notation to tshark filter notation

Tags: filter, wireshark, tshark

I want to filter a pcap file with tshark (linux, command line).

The notation of my filter in wireshark @ windows is:

```
frame.time >= "2017-07-11 13:37:07" && frame.time <= "2017-07-11 13:37:11"
```

So what's the right notation for tshark in linux?

After several trials I haven't found the right solution yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahhh now I've found the solution to my question!!

Replacing the tshark filter "frame.time" through "frame.time_epoch" and for example "2017-07-11 13:37:10" through "1499773030.999955000" causes the packet to be filtered out. :)))

Comment: For my answer, I've only checked the syntactic point of view. If you are satisfied with your own answer you can mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `-Y` option.

> -Y
>
> Cause the specified filter (which uses the syntax of read/display filters, rather than that of capture filters) to be applied before printing a decoded form of packets or writing packets to a file.

Because of [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), you have also to escape the display filter with [single quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Single-Quotes):

```
tshark -Y 'frame.time >= "2017-07-11 13:37:07" && frame.time <= "2017-07-11 13:37:11"'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The command works without errors, but there aren't any packets in the new pcap file. If I have a pcap file with 1 packet, and I run your tshark command with the adapted packet time of course, then no packet is filtered out to a new pcap file...........

Comment: Try it out. Filter out a packet based on its arrival time from a pcap file and save it to an other pcap file. Code: tshark -r infile.pcap -w outfile.pcap -Y 'frame.time >= "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" && frame.time <= "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"'